# Excel VBA - Stored Procedure (SQL Server)

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, vba, excel-2010

I have a slight issue retrieving multiple recordsets (with column names) and pasting the data into an Excel sheet, like the image below

[image]

The VBA code that I have just retrieves the first recordset but not the rest

Any help will be much appreciated, thank you

```vb
Sub CProcedure()

    Dim Conn As ADODB.Connection, RecordSet As ADODB.RecordSet
    Dim Command As ADODB.Command
    Dim ConnectionString As String, StoredProcName As String
    Dim range1 As ADODB.Parameter, range2 As ADODB.Parameter
    Dim SP_Param1 As String
    Dim SP_Param2 As String

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set Conn = New ADODB.Connection
    Set RecordSet = New ADODB.RecordSet
    Set Command = New ADODB.Command

    ServerName = "1111"
    DatabaseName = "dataReporting"
    UserId = "88888"
    Password = "88888"
    SP_Param1 = "StartDate"
    SP_Param2 = "EndDate"
    StoredProcName = "KPI_Report"

    ConnectionString = "PROVIDER=SQLOLEDB;DATA SOURCE=" & ServerName & _
                       ";INITIAL CATALOG=" & DatabaseName & "; User Id=" & _
                       UserId & "; Password=" & Password & ";"
    Conn.Open ConnectionString

    With Command
        .ActiveConnection = Conn
        .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
        .CommandText = StoredProcName
        .CommandTimeout = 0
    End With

    Set range1 = Command.CreateParameter(SP_Param1, adDBDate, adParamInput, , DateSerial(2018, 1, 1))
    Command.Parameters.Append range1

    Set range2 = Command.CreateParameter(SP_Param2, adDBDate, adParamInput, , DateSerial(2018, 4, 1))
    Command.Parameters.Append range2

    Set RecordSet = Command.Execute
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset RecordSet

    RecordSet.Close
    Conn.Close
    On Error GoTo 0
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Exit Sub


End Sub
```

Update

I added the below loop but still no luck

```vb
'Loop through recordset and place values
RecordSet.MoveFirst
Do While RecordSet.EOF = False
    For i = 0 To RecordSet.Fields.Count - 1
        ActiveCell.Value = RecordSet.Fields(i).Value
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate
    Next i
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, -i).Activate
RecordSet.MoveNext
Loop
```

This is the stored procedure code:

```vb
Sub storedproc()

Dim Conn As ADODB.Connection
Dim ADODBCmd As ADODB.Command
Dim rs As ADODB.RecordSet
Dim i As Integer
Dim sConnect As String

    ServerName = "1111"
    DatabaseName = "dataReporting"
    UserId = "88888"
    Password = "88888"
    SP_Param1 = "StartDate"
    SP_Param2 = "EndDate"
    StoredProcName = "KPI_Report"

 sConnect = "PROVIDER=SQLOLEDB;DATA SOURCE=" & ServerName & 
";INITIAL CATALOG=" & DatabaseName & "; User Id=" & UserId & 
"; Password=" & Password & ";"


'Establish connection
Set Conn = New ADODB.Connection
Conn.ConnectionString = sConnect
Conn.Open

'Open recordset
Set ADODBCmd = New ADODB.Command
ADODBCmd.ActiveConnection = Conn
ADODBCmd.CommandText = StoredProcName
ADODBCmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
ADODBCmd.CommandTimeout = 0

Set range1 = ADODBCmd.CreateParameter(SP_Param1, adDBDate, adParamInput, , DateSerial(2018, 1, 1))
ADODBCmd.Parameters.Append range1

Set range2 = ADODBCmd.CreateParameter(SP_Param2, adDBDate, adParamInput, , DateSerial(2018, 4, 1))
ADODBCmd.Parameters.Append range2

Set rs = ADODBCmd.Execute()

'Loop through recordset and place values
rs.MoveFirst
Do While rs.EOF = False
    For i = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1
        ActiveCell.Value = rs.Fields(i).Value  
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate        
    Next i
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, -i).Activate           
rs.MoveNext
Loop


'Clean up
rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing

 End Sub
```

Comment: You need to invoke the [`NextRecordset` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/nextrecordset-method-ado) to return multiple result sets,

Comment: @DanGuzman i tried adding the next recordset but no luck

Comment: Add the proc code to you question.

Comment: @DanGuzman i tried to do a loop with nextrecordset with BOF and EOF are True  https://www.w3schools.com/asp/met_rs_nextrecordset.asp

Comment: Again, add the proc code to your question (obfuscated if needed). The proc and app code work in concert with one another and I want to make sure we have all the information needed to help you.

Comment: @DanGuzman any assistance or advice would be much appreciated

Comment: I'd be happy to help. Still waiting for the proc code.

Comment: @DanGuzman Many thanks Proc Code now included

Comment: @Elixir, I think you'll find out he means the code for the stored procedure KPI_Report

Comment: a strored with Select Top 1 .......will at most return only one record. @DanGuzman, is asking for the proc for similar reasons. Share it if you need any help.

Comment: @Elixir, yes, I mean the T-SQL code for stored procedure `KPI_Report`,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer of *S Meaden* mentioning the `GetNextRecordSet` solves your issue having multiple recordsets as result of a stored proc.
The following code dumps all recordsets, including the field names, into a sheet (do not forget to cleanup the sheet first if you run it repeatedly).

```
...
Set rs = Command.Execute
Dim startcol As Long
startcol = 1
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    Do While Not rs Is Nothing

        Dim col As Long
        For col = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1
            .Cells(1, startcol + col) = rs.Fields(col).Name
        Next col
        .Cells(2, startcol).CopyFromRecordset rs

        startcol = startcol + rs.Fields.Count + 1
        Set rs = rs.NextRecordset
    Loop
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

So the Stored procedure needs to return more than one recordset such as

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetCarsAndCategories
AS
BEGIN
SELECT * FROM Cars
SELECT * FROM Categories
END
```

and then the VBA code initially has access to the Cars recordset and to get to the Categories recordset one calls `GetNextRecordSet`